# PHP convert query to DATE

Tags: php, date

I have this code. my problem is the `strduedate` field is in `varchar` type. How can I convert that field into `datetime` so I can perform the greater than query.

scenario.

Given the `strduedate` in my database is = '01/02/2016'

when I perform the query it says that `strduedate` is less than current date which is 09/18/2015.

```
$date_now = new DateTime();

$sql = "UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no' WHERE strduedate > '$date_now' ";
$OverDue->updatefields($sql);
```

Comment: [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) - `STR_TO_DATE(strduedate, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the mysql STR_TO_DATE function like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no' WHERE STR_TO_DATE(strduedate, '%m/%d/%Y') > '$date_now' ";
$OverDue->updatefields($sql);
```